# How to Dynamically Generate ToggleButtons which must be placed inside a Dynamically generated Groupboxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, toggle

I am a C++ developer and recently moved to C#. I am working on WPF app which deals with dynamic generation of groupboxes. The UI components like RadioButton, togglebutton etc present in respective groupbox must inturn be generated dynamically.

Currently I have 2 xaml files `CodecView.xaml` and `CodecWidgetView.xaml`, a separate viewmodel class for both the xaml files. Well This dynamic generation is interesting but surely a tricky situation for me. Let me show you the code in which I have dynamically generated set of groupboxes.

**CodecView.xaml:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CWDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5,5,0,0"/>
            <local:CodecWidgetView Margin="5,10,5,5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource styleBackground}">          
        <Grid Name="NumberofCodecs" >
            <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CWDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding CodecWidgets}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>            
 </Grid>
```

**CodecWidgetView.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ToggleButton Name="MasterBox" Content="Master" Command="{Binding MasterCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding MasterCheck}" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ModesList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModesList, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedIndex="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FrequencyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFrequencyList, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedIndex="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="80" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                //Here I want to dynamically generate 4 radio buttons
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Label Name="BitDelay" Content="Bit Delay" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,205,0" Height="25" Width="55" />
                <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Value="{Binding BitDelayValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="255.0" TickFrequency="1.0" Margin="95,0,0,0" Name="bitdelayslider" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160" />
                <TextBox Name="BitDelayValue" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding ElementName=bitdelayslider,Path=Value, StringFormat=0.0}" Width="40" Height="20" Margin="0,0,110,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                <Label Name="DBGain" Content="DB Gain" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,205,0" Height="25" Width="55" />
                <TextBox Name="DBGainValue" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding ElementName=dbgainslider,Path=Value, StringFormat=0.0}" Width="40" Height="20" Margin="0,0,110,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Value="{Binding DBGainValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="59.5" TickFrequency="0.5" Margin="95,0,0,0" Name="dbgainslider" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

**CodecViewModel.cs:**

```
public ObservableCollection<CodecWidgetViewModel> CodecWidgets { get; set; }

    public CodecViewModel()
    {
        CodecWidgets = new ObservableCollection<CodecWidgetViewModel>();
        CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 8  - Dig Mic A" });
        CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 9  - Dig Mic B" });
        CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 10  - PCM A 3P3V" });
        CodecWidgets.Add(new CodecWidgetViewModel { Description = "Location 11  - PCM B 3P3V" });
    }
```

**CodecWidgetViewModel.cs:**

```
private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get
        { 
            return _description; 
        }

        set
        {
            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }
```

This gives me 4 groupboxes on startup. Now here is the requirement:

1. Have a look at the `CodecWidgetView.xaml` and you will find me adding combobox's, slider etc. but in `Grid.Row=2` I wanna dynamically generate 4 toggle buttons with Content as: `16 Bit, 20 Bit, 24 Bit and 32 Bit`.
2. Once this happens there must be just one click event on this button which sets the togglestate and executes some statements.

This is how I had done in C++:

```
//In Constructor
for(int jj = 0; jj < 4; jj++)
{
    m_codecBitLengthButton[jj] = new ToggleButton(bitLengthes[jj]); //Here bitlength consists of 16Bit, 20Bit, 24Bit and 32Bit
    m_codecBitLengthButton[jj]->setRadioGroupId(55); // make a custom group ID
    addAndMakeVisible(m_codecBitLengthButton[jj]);
    m_codecBitLengthButton[jj]->addButtonListener(this);
    m_codecBitLengthButton[jj]->setToggleState(false, false);
}
// check which button should be pressed
    cmd = (0x9400 | (m_slot & 0xFF));
m_msp430->ReadInternalCommand(cmd, 1, readBuf); //This returns some value in readBuf
m_bitLength = readBuf[0];
m_codecBitLengthButton[readBuf[0]]->setToggleState(true, false); //Togglestate set to true on startup based on readBuf[0]


//Gets called when any of the toggle button is clicked
while(jj < 4)
{
    if(button == m_codecBitLengthButton[jj])
    {
        // add code for bit length support
        cmd = ((CODEC_LENGTH_CMD & 0x7F00) | (m_slot & 0xFF));
        sendBuf[numBytes++] = jj; // this should represent the proper number of bits
        m_bitLength = jj;
        break;
    }
    jj++;
}
```

How can i achieve the same thing in C#? :)

Comment: Are the Content's on these buttons dynamic? or what do you mean by dynamic generated? if there are always 4 buttons simply add them to the xaml

Comment: @Mark: You are back mate :) Well there are 4 buttons only and all of them execute almost same set of statements with minor changes. Mind you the content of these button must be generated dynamically. I mean Btn1 name is 16 Bit, Btn2 name is 20Bit and so on. Based on for loop, I just want to generate them in such a way that I can have a single click method which takes care of togglestate and so on rather than repeating it 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with an Command:

**CodecWidgetView.xaml:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition />
           <ColumnDefinition />
           <ColumnDefinition />
           <ColumnDefinition />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Content="16Bit" Command="{Binding Path=ToogleButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="16"/>
     <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" Content="20Bit" Command="{Binding Path=ToogleButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="20"/>
     <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Content="24Bit" Command="{Binding Path=ToogleButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="24"/>
     <ToggleButton Grid.Column="3" Content="32Bit" Command="{Binding Path=ToogleButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="32"/>
</Grid>
```

that will be really simpler and in an mvvm way.

the Benefits are you can specify which Parameter the CommandParameter will be. In the Sample i hardcoded it, but it can also be bind.

**CodecWidgetViewModel.cs:**

```
    RelayCommand _toogleButtonCommand;
    public ICommand ToogleButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_toogleButtonCommand == null)
            {
                _toogleButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(this.DoSomethingExecute,
                    this.DoSomethingCanExecute);
            }
            return _toogleButtonCommand;
        }
    }

    public void DoSomethingExecute(object param)
    {
       int result = Convert.ToInt32(param);

        if (result == 16)
        {
            //To this and so on for example
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
To define which button IsChecked at anytime bind the ToogleButtons IsChecked Property in your ViewModel and a Property for the Value of the ToogleButton.

```
private bool _isCheckedToogle1;
public bool IsCheckedToogle1
{
    get { return _isCheckedToogle1; }
    set
    {
        _isCheckedToogle1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsCheckedToogle1");
    }
}

private int _toogleButton1Value = 16;
public int ToogleButton1Value
{
   get { return _toogleButton1Value; }
   set
   {
      _toogleButton1Value = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("ToogleButton1Value");
   }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" x:Name="toogleButton1" Content="16Bit" Command="{Binding Path=ToogleButtonCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCheckedToogle1}" >
    <ToggleButton.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
             <Binding Path="ToggleButton1Value" />
             <Binding />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ToggleButton.CommandParameter>
</ToggleButton>
```

Because it is now a MutliBinding you need an Converter and a Class for the New Value which is the Parameter:

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ToggleValue val = new ToggleValue();
        val.View = values[1] as CodecWidgetViewModel;
        val.Value = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
        return val;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
}

public class ToggleValue
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public CodecWidgetViewModel View { get; set; }
}
```

And your new CommandLogik

```
    public void DoSomethingExecute(object param)
    {
        ToggleValue result = param as ToggleValue;

        if (result.Value == 16)
        {
            result.View.IsCheckedToogle1 = true;
            result.View.IsCheckedToogle2 = false;
            result.View.IsCheckedToogle3 = false;
            result.View.IsCheckedToogle4 = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Alright bro as always your code works well :) Now here I want all 4 buttons to behave like a radiobutton i.e. at one time only one will be checked. Secondly if you check the code: `cmd = (0x9400 | (m_slot & 0xFF));
m_msp430->ReadInternalCommand(cmd, 1, readBuf); //This returns some value in readBuf
m_bitLength = readBuf[0];
m_codecBitLengthButton[readBuf[0]]->setToggleState(true, false);` in my example you will find `readBuf[0] setting one button as checked on startup since this code is present in constructor. How can i achieve it in your method?

Comment: threr are some possibilities to do that give me a couple minutes i will update

Comment: Throws exception at `<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">` as `Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.`

Comment: yeah sure... you have to add the converter to your resources. for example  <Grid.Resources>
            <converter:ToggleConverter x:Key="Converter" />
        </Grid.Resources>

Comment: Although it runs now but throws an exception at `if (result.Value == 16)` as `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` whenever I click any button.

Comment: which button ? i have made a full example and it runs at my place. You only Changed it for the First ToggleButton you have to add all the lines of code for the other ToggleButtons aswell

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18227/discussion-between-stonedjesus-and-mark)